# Why is my HTML button not working when trying to switch to different section of webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new and I am working on my website. My hosting service is IPage. When I try changing to a different section of the website with a button it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<button onclick='https://rgulewicz2438602.ipage.com/About.html'>About</button>
```

Comment: Good question, but please search before asking, there are several good answers to this question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is call for a event, so u need put an action on him, not url.
To redirect to another page you can use `window.location`, like this:

```html
<button onclick='window.location="https://rgulewicz2438602.ipage.com/About.html"'>About</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an anchor tag to change the location of a page, like so:

```html
<a class="btn" href='https://rgulewicz2438602.ipage.com/About.html'>About</a>
```

then you can style it using css to look like a button

some example styles might be something like:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a site use either `window.open` with JavaScript or better still use a link which has an attribute of `target="_blank"`

Try this:

```css
a {
  background: #aaf;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 4px;
}
a:hover {
  background: #ddf;
}
a:active {
  background: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://rgulewicz2438602.ipage.com/About.html">About</a>
```